# Cake PHP DataTable Component destroys Form validation

Tags: database, validation, cakephp, controller, components

There is an issue with the js-plugin DataTables. To get it working I implemented the DataTableComponent of Chris Nizzardini: https://github.com/cnizzdotcom/cakephp-datatable

That works completely fine. But when I want to save a form on the page which contains that DataTable, Cake throws a Database Error, integrity constraint violation with fields cannot be null.

All I know is:
The form validation works fine when in the controller the line

```
public $components = array('RequestHandler', 'Session', 'DataTable');
```

is changed to that line:

```
public $components = array('RequestHandler', 'Session');
```

I can change the code in the controller without getting rid of the error so I assume that in the Component the validation is omitted.

The controller code:

```
if (!$this->request->isPost()) {
            $this->paginate = array(
                'fields' => array('Post.id', 'Post.B/S', 'Post.H', 'Post.DATE', 'Post.TIME', 'Post.INCOME', 'Post.CART'),
                'conditions' => array('OR' =>
                    array(
                       array('AND' => array(    
                                      array('Post.ZIPCODE LIKE' => $userArea . '%'),
                                      array('Post.ALTDATE >' => date("Y-m-d")),
                                      array('Post.AGENT' => '0'),
                                      array('Post.OWNER <>' => $this->UserAuth->getUserId()),
                                      array('Post.PARENTID' => '0'),
                                      array('Post.ACCEPTED' => '0')
                                )),
                        array('AND' => array(
                                      array('Post.ZIPCODE' => $userArea . '%'),
                                      array('Post.ALTDATE' => date("Y-m-d")),
                                      array('Post.TIME >' => date("H:i")),
                                      array('Post.AGENT' => '0'),
                                      array('Post.OWNER <>' => $this->UserAuth->getUserId()),
                                      array('Post.PARENTID' => '0'),
                                      array('Post.ACCEPTED' => '0')
                                )),
                        array('AND' => array(   
                                      array('Post.DELIVERYAREA LIKE' => $userArea . '%'),
                                      array('Post.ALTDATE >' => date("Y-m-d")),
                                      array('Post.AGENT' => '0'),
                                      array('Post.OWNER <>' => $this->UserAuth->getUserId()),
                                      array('Post.PARENTID' => '0'),
                                      array('Post.ACCEPTED' => '0')
                                )),
                        array('AND' => array(
                                      array('Post.DELIVERYAREA' => $userArea . '%'),
                                      array('Post.ALTDATE' => date("Y-m-d")),
                                      array('Post.TIME >' => date("H:i")),
                                      array('Post.AGENT' => '0'),
                                      array('Post.OWNER <>' => $this->UserAuth->getUserId()),
                                      array('Post.PARENTID' => '0'),
                                      array('Post.ACCEPTED' => '0')
                                )),
                    )
                )
            );
            $response = $this->DataTable->getResponse();
            $this->set('response', $response);
            $this->set('_serialize','response');
            $response['oLanguage'] = array('sUrl' => 'language/dataTables.german.txt');
        };
```

My question: Is there a possibility to route the request through the component and run it after fetching that data so that the Database Error vanishes? Thanks to you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to not use getResponse() but getResponse(model, action). The second has to be used because the first one is broken per code in that plugin. The developer has to fix that.